# Img Downloads & Save .... different behaviur in module Application ....

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air

I developed awhile ago an App. for downloading Images onto the AIR desktop which works perfectly fine! yet when I wanted to use it within one of my many modules in a large AIR Application I got over & over that the FileStream(s) were not open to SAVE.

So I build another App. with one of my saved DB codes (as below) which has NO error msg with a FileStream problem once included into the App. with the modules yet the error which comes up this time is (Error #2044; Unhandled IOErrorEvent: text=Error #2035: URL Not Found).

I can't think of anything why this should not work or better why the FileStrems are not opening or why as in this case the URL is not found??? as both work OK in its own Applications.

Any help would be appreciated! regards aktell

```
.......................................................................................
creationComplete="loadRemoteImage(textInputOne.text)">

<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;

        private var _bitmapDataOne:BitmapData;

        private function loadRemoteImage(url:String):void {

            var loaderOne:Loader = new Loader();

            loaderOne.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
            loaderOne.load(new URLRequest(url));
        }

        private function completeHandler(event:Event):void {

            var loaderInfoOne:LoaderInfo = event.target as LoaderInfo;
            imgOne.source = loaderInfoOne.content;

            var bitmapOne:Bitmap = loaderInfoOne.content as Bitmap;
            _bitmapDataOne = bitmapOne.bitmapData;


            saveImage();
        }

        private function saveImage():void {

            var extensionOne:String;
            var imgByteArrayOne:ByteArray;

            if(textInputOne.text.indexOf('.jpg') != -1) {

                var jpegEncoderOne:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder(100);
                imgByteArrayOne = jpegEncoderOne.encode(_bitmapDataOne);
                extensionOne = '.jpg';
            }
            else
                return;

            var fileOne:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath('Files/test'+ extensionOne);
            var fileStreamOne:FileStream = new FileStream();

            fileStreamOne.open(fileOne, FileMode.WRITE);
            fileStreamOne.writeBytes(imgByteArrayOne);

            fileStreamOne.close();
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>

<mx:TextInput 
    id="textInputOne"
    text="com/waterfront.jpg"
    visible="false"/>

<mx:SWFLoader 
    id="imgOne"/>
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the url is corect? Can you paste the exact stream error you get with error code and full message stack trace

Comment: The error code is what I wrote above! Nothing more - Nothing less! and YES the URL is also what it is for testing & the Img is also at that URL that is why it baffles me! it just does not work in a module otherwise perfect!

Comment: when does appear the error ? loading the image or saving ? did you try to trace the url in the loadRemoteImage function ?

Comment: Well, finally got somewhere to make this all work! as after reading a few items I found and got this of .... http://www.pavlasek.sk/devel/?p=10 ...., and which gave me the idea to try it in two(2) stage step way (Flash Player 10 onwards) which I also read somewhere else so that worked perfectly well!!! thanks anyway aktell

Comment: **** Flex 10 – upload files using URLRequest

In Flash player it was possible until version 10 to upload files only by FileReference.upload method (there were some ugly hacks – such as uploading in external iframe).

Uploading files using directly FileReference.upload has some serious problems problems. Especially on Firefox, Flash player plugin creates it’s own request (different UserAgent, session and so) so on server it is handled in different session. All the parameters has to be sent, or some hacks has to be done (I manually set the jsessionid to each request). ****